# how to include cc copy in email notification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications

How am I include the sender/creator in email notification in my project?
This code is working fine and it notifies all the persons tagged in Assigned To textfield. And now how can I include in CC copy the person who created the report?.

The string created_by is the employee number of the person who created the report and the ad_users table is where all the employee number and email addresses can be found. How can I get the email address of the person who created the report?

```
 public void SendEmail(Guid[] UsersID,
                                string ir_no,
                                string place,
                                int? hn,
                                int? age,
                                string gender,
                                string persons_involved,
                                string incidentName,
                                string narrative_report,
                                DateTime? created_date,
                                string created_by,
                                Guid IRID)
    {
        var Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpClient"].ToString();
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPassword"].ToString();
        var FromEmailID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromMail"].ToString();
        var port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"].ToString();
        var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"].ToString();

        var incident_name = (from i in db.All_Issues
                             select i.Incident_Patient_Name);


        //Users already Activated the accounts
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(FromEmailID);
        //MailAddress copy = new MailAddress(irCreatorEmail);
        //mail.CC.Add(copy);
        mail.Subject = "Sample Email";

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");


        //Users not yet Activated
        MailMessage mail2 = new MailMessage();
        mail2.From = new MailAddress(FromEmailID);
        //MailAddress copy2 = new MailAddress(irCreatorEmail);
        //mail2.CC.Add(copy2);
        mail2.Subject = "Sample Email";
        mail2.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail2.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");


        SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpclient.Host = Host;
        smtpclient.Port = Convert.ToInt32(port);
        smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);

        smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;

        List<ad_users> users = db.ad_users.ToList();

        if (UsersID != null)
        {
            foreach (var Users in UsersID)
            {
                foreach (var usersList in users)
                {
                    if (Users == usersList.user_id)
                    {
                        var adUsersList = db.ad_users.Find(Users);
                        var emp = adUsersList.employee_nr;


                        if (emp != null)
                        {
                            mail.Body = EmailMessage(ir_no,
                                                    place,
                                                    hn,
                                                    age,
                                                    gender,
                                                    persons_involved,
                                                    incidentName,
                                                    narrative_report,
                                                    created_date,
                                                    created_by,
                                                    IRID);
                            mail.To.Add(usersList.email_address);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mail2.Body = EmailMessageNotActivated(ir_no,
                                                    place,
                                                    hn,
                                                    age,
                                                    gender,
                                                    persons_involved,
                                                    incidentName,
                                                    narrative_report,
                                                    created_date,
                                                    created_by,
                                                    IRID);
                            mail2.To.Add(usersList.email_address);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            try
            {
                smtpclient.Send(mail);
                smtpclient.Send(mail2);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException /*ex*/)
            {
                //ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found the solution in this problem. Just took a long time for posting here for update.

I found the answer by using a Helper wherein, I can get the email of the creator.

```
public static string GetEmailOfIRCreator(this string empNo)
    {
        IREntities dbIMR = new IREntities();
        var email = dbIMR.ad_users.Where(a => a.employee_nr == empNo).Select(a => a.email_address).FirstOrDefault();
        return email;
    }
```

Then I use this helper in my class on sending email notification.

```
var irCreator = created_by_emp_nr.GetEmailOfIRCreator();

if (mail.To.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (irCreator != null)
                    {
                        mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(irCreator));
                    }
                    client.Send(mail);
                }
```

And that's it. I already send an email notification to creator as cc copy.
Hoping this can also help someone.